# Failed to load “libpepflashplayer.so” on Firefox - Ubuntu

Tags: firefox, flash

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and my browser is Firefox 57.0.1

In some websites (like [this site](http://www.investsite.com.br/graficos_desempenho_operacional.php?cod_negociacao=TCSA3) ), the error message below appears where it's supposed to be a flash object

[image]

I had already installed the Freashwrapper (pepper flash).

The original plugin file ( libfreshwrapper-flashplayer.so ) was located in the directory: /usr/lib/browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash

I tried to solve the issue copying this file to : /usr/lib/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so

But the error is still there. Can someone help me?

Comment: Just remove the freshwrapper and pepper flash plug-ins? It's not necessary to use it to get the latest version of flash any more, as Adobe has released an NPAPI build, which you should have installed with the `adobe-flashplugin` package.

Comment: What @dobey says is true most of the time. Check out [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html) for a more complete description.

Comment: Thank you guys, it worked. I had tried to install adobe-flashplugin on the terminal before, but for some reason it didn't work.

Comment: @dobey, for arm based systems pepperflash is the only option. What can be done in that case?

Comment: @BigBadCat I guess if you really need Flash on ARM, you should probably use Chromium then (at least for those sites where Flash is needed).

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by typing this command :

sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree

hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed [adobe-flashplugin](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/adobe-flashplugin/) - as suggested by @dobey and @Gunnar - and it worked.
I didn't remove freshwrapper / pepperflash

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same "Failed to Load
Libpepflashplayer.so" today in my firefox (ESR 52.5.3 64bit on
Ubuntu 16.04) when accessing vSphere web portal.

Fix:

0. close firefox

1. download Adobe Flashplayer tar.gz from
https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/

2. extract

3. move the libpepflashplayser.so to your browser's plugin
folder. Mine was /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/

4. relaunched firefox, works!

Hope this helps. This site has been mad helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to load a 32 bit version of a library on a 64 bit system this will not work.

As far as I know, there is no 64 bit version of this library for either Linux or Android on ARM.

You can verify if the library matches your architecture using `uname` and file (on the library).

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was quite easy. The steps are below (I made this procedure).

1. Open your browser (any browser) and go to get.adobe.com/flashplayer/
2. Click on the drop-down menu and click on 'tar.gz for Linux' and click Download.
3. Fire up the terminal and type `sudo nautilus` or any other file manager other than nautilus if you do have one.
4. Go to your home directory and copy the 'libflashplayer.so' file.
5. Go back to the filesystem and go to `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugin/`. If you don't have the `mozilla` and the `plugin` folder, create one. This wouldn't do any harm.
6. Paste the file in the `plugin` folder and restart your Firefox browser (i'm not sure about it's derivatives)
7. There you go! Now flash should now work on Firefox (through it's going to discontinued).