# adobe-flashplugin provides out of date Flash

Tags: firefox, flash

**Not a duplicate as per the answer!**

This is my first posting here and I'm still a novice user of Ubuntu. I use Ubuntu 17.10 and Firefox 59.0.2 (64 bits). I've already installed the flash plug-in as I read [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html), but I still can't load a website using flash (Adobe Connect). I've got the same problem like [this person](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984246/failed-to-load-libpepflashplayer-so-on-firefox-ubuntu). Now, instead of that screen, I see a white screen. Then I tried to install the plug-in for freshplayer-pepperflash with the terminal:

```
sudo apt install browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash
```

but the package couldn't be found. Thanks in advanced for your help.

Screenshot before installing flash plug-in:
[image]

Screenshot after installing flash plug-in:
[image]

Comment: There's no need to install any pepperflash packages. Just install `adobe-flashplugin` and you will get the latest flash plug-in installed.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson , yes, that's it. I found it in the site help.ubuntu.com linked above.

Comment: @dobey : As I said, I've already installed Flash player, but it didn't work either. So I think it must be something else.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I am absolutely sure about it. What specific information are you asking about on that link? Nowhere does it say that freshplayer-pepperflash is _needed_. It probably should not recommend how to install it any longer, though.

Comment: I added two screenshots to ilustrate what I am saying.

Comment: @DoktorFaustus Get rid of the freshplayer wrapper stuff. It is not necessary to get an updated flash in Firefox any more.

Comment: @dobey : I can do it, but I don't see that it is going to solve my problem.

Comment: But OP already has freshwrapper and adobe-flashplugin installed apparently. From the screenshot, it sounds like maybe Adobe Connect support should be queried, or at least the problem needs better explained. The issue isn't installation of flash, for the mentioned web site. Does the site work fine in Chromium instead?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Look at the "after installing flash plug-in" screenshot too. It simply says "go to our support page". The former screenshot shows freshplayer installed without the flash plug-in. The latter shows with both.

Comment: I took the liberty to change the title of this question, to make it more easily found. I also removed all my previous comments, and would suggest that Doktor Faustus and @dobey do the same.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate, and should be re-opened. The OP asked for help with handling a situation, which proved to be caused by an `adobe-flashplugin` bug which happened 2018-04-10. The answer provides a workaround until the bug has been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Did some research, and found an issue with the `adobe-flashplugin` package. Reported as [bug #1767476](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1767476).

Since you are using Firefox, I would recommend these steps for now:

1. Uninstall the Flash related packages you may have installed:

   ```
   sudo apt purge adobe-flashplugin browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash
   ```
2. Install the `flashplugin-installer` package:

   ```
   sudo apt install flashplugin-installer
   ```
3. Restart your web browser.

*Edit 2018-04-28:*

The bug seems to have been fixed, so [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html) ought to apply as usual again.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Gunnar, it worked! I followed exactly those steps, and now I can load the site and use this utility. You have no idea how much you helped me. Thanks to @dobey too. You guys are amazing!

Comment: @DoktorFaustus: Glad to hear that. You had the bad luck to run into a bug. The good news is that thanks to your question that bug is now reported.